# How to get the index of clicked element by class?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to get the index of the clicked element in its list as well in its `.blue` class.

I figured out how to get the index in its list, but I can't figure out how to get the index in its `.blue` class. For example when I click the 5th button I want the to show 'index 4 - class index 3'.

Any ideas?

```js
$('.showindex').click(function() {
  var index = $(this).closest("li").index();
  console.log("index " + index + " - class index " + "?");
});
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ol id="ol1">
  <li><input type="button" value="Show index" class="showindex blue">showindex blue</li>
  <li><input type="button" value="Show index" class="showindex">showindex</li>
  <li><input type="button" value="Show index" class="showindex blue">showindex blue</li>
  <li><input type="button" value="Show index" class="showindex">showindex</li>
  <li><input type="button" value="Show index" class="showindex blue">showindex blue</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I guess you already figured out how to find *all* elements with the `blue` class in order? If you don't have a million elements it will be fine

Comment: You can pass an argument to the `index()` method like: `var blueIndex = $('.blue').index($(this));`. Be aware that it returns `-1` if it can't find anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can select all `.blue` elements and provide the current element as an argument to find its index within that collection.

Note that the last button will show its 'class index' as `2` because indexes are zero-based in JS. Try this:

```js
let $blues = $('li:has(.showindex.blue)');

$('.showindex').click(function() {
  let $li = $(this).closest('li');
  let index = $li.index();
  let classIndex = $blues.index($li);
  
  console.log(`index ${index}, class index ${classIndex}`);
});
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ol id="ol1">
  <li><input type="button" value="Show index" class="showindex blue">showindex blue</li>
  <li><input type="button" value="Show index" class="showindex">showindex</li>
  <li><input type="button" value="Show index" class="showindex blue">showindex blue</li>
  <li><input type="button" value="Show index" class="showindex">showindex</li>
  <li><input type="button" value="Show index" class="showindex blue">showindex blue/li>
</ol>
```

Comment: If he want normal number just add `+1` to `classIndex`